# unix script archive log files older than 15 days

Tags: linux, unix

I have a list of log files in a directory, which are piled for more than a year now. I've written the below script to archive the log files which are older than 15 days.

***Script:***

```
#!/bin/bash
files=($(find /opt/Informatica/9.5.1/server/infa_shared/SessLogs -type f -mtime +15))
file=SessLog_bkup_`date +"%y-%m-%d"`.tar.gz
Backup=/opt/Informatica/9.5.1/server/infa_shared/SessLogs/Backup
tar -zcf $file --remove-files "${files[@]}"
mv $file $Backup
```

But, when I run the script it throws below error

***Error:***

> ./backuplogs.sh: line 5: /bin/tar: Argument list too long.

Please advise if I'm missing something in the script

thanks for the help
Kiran

Comment: The standard solution for that is [`logrotate`](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is due to failure of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) of `/bin/tar` by your shell with `E2BIG`.

Read the man page of [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html). You could use

> `-T`, `--files-from`=*FILE*
>
> Get names to extract or create from *FILE*.

and combine that with some other parts of your script (e.g. redirecting the `find` command output to some temporary file, to be passed by `-T` to `tar` ....).

But as commented by [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) you really want [logrotate(8)](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

You could also use other archivers, e.g. [afio(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/afio)